# Scriptlistener Plugin : Catch layers transformation value

Tags: photoshop-scripting

I'm making a plugin called [PS-Blender](https://mr0nline.github.io/PS-Blender) where I'm trying to simulate the functionality of Illustrator's blend tool. I've used different text field to measure out the start and end values of positions and rotations etc but I think it'll far better if user just have to transform the object and plugin detects transform automatically...

So far, I'll do something like below (just a prototype)

```js
function get_start_layer_data(){
//Initial values will be stored like rotation, position etc.
}
alert("Please place your object to desired location")
function get_new_data(){
//new data based on user's transformation
}
```

So, I started to figure out if I can track the transform but it seems doesn't working but I can see the transformation being recorded in ScriptListener Plugin and below is the code where it finds everything including position, rotation changes so there must be a way to track it.

```js
var idTrnf = charIDToTypeID( "Trnf" );
    var desc40 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref6 = new ActionReference();
        var idPath = charIDToTypeID( "Path" );
        var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
        var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
        ref6.putEnumerated( idPath, idOrdn, idTrgt );
    desc40.putReference( idnull, ref6 );
    var idFTcs = charIDToTypeID( "FTcs" );
    var idQCSt = charIDToTypeID( "QCSt" );
    var idQcsa = charIDToTypeID( "Qcsa" );
    desc40.putEnumerated( idFTcs, idQCSt, idQcsa );
    var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
        var desc41 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc41.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idPxl, 348.000000 );
        var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc41.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idPxl, 168.000000 );
    var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
    desc40.putObject( idOfst, idOfst, desc41 );
    var idWdth = charIDToTypeID( "Wdth" );
    var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
    desc40.putUnitDouble( idWdth, idPrc, 38.750000 );
    var idHght = charIDToTypeID( "Hght" );
    var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
    desc40.putUnitDouble( idHght, idPrc, 71.428571 );
    var idAngl = charIDToTypeID( "Angl" );
    var idAng = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
    desc40.putUnitDouble( idAngl, idAng, 69.791238 );
    var idLnkd = charIDToTypeID( "Lnkd" );
    desc40.putBoolean( idLnkd, true );
executeAction( idTrnf, desc40, DialogModes.NO );
```

If anyone got idea how I can track these data and import them to variables then let me know! or even better if you guys want to contribute to project since it's open-source.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Why dont you just decompose those values from the layers transform matrix?

Comment: @joojaa I see 4 points of  a smart object are available in its descriptor but I don't think that's a transformation matrix? could you please give an example of decomposing it to values for free transform?

Comment: @joojaa by what you mean transformation matrix? because it's totally new word for me and as Sergey told it would help me understand even better if you can provide me some links or example :)